# Error with generators of Lorentz group (basis of Lorentz Lie algebra)

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, group-theory, lorentz-symmetry, lie-algebra

Can someone help me figure out why my $J_y$ is incorrect? :/ It's supposed to be \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & -1 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}

My work:

To calculate the basis of Lorentz Lie algebra (or equivalently the generators of the Lorentz Lie group), $J_x,J_y,J_z,K_x,K_y,K_z$, we take the matrices $R(\hat{i},\theta)$ and $\beta(\hat{i},\delta)$ (that are respectively matrix representations for counter-clockwise rotations about the i-axis by an angle $\theta$, as well as matrix representations for Lorentz boosts in the i-axis direction with rapidity $\delta$) and respectively apply the following formulas, $J_i=i\frac{\partial R(\hat{i},\theta)}{\partial\theta}\mid_{\theta=0}$ and $K_i=-i\frac{\partial \beta(\hat{i},\delta)}{\partial\delta}\mid_{\delta=0}$.

To get $J_x$ we begin

$R(\hat{x},\theta)$ =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) \\
  0 & 0 & sin(\theta) & cos(\theta) 
 \end{pmatrix}

Differentiating with respect to $\theta$ we have

\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -sin(\theta) & -cos(\theta) \\
  0 & 0 & cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) 
 \end{pmatrix}

and then taking the limit as $\theta$ goes to zero, we get

$J_x$ =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}

To get $J_y$ we begin

$R(\hat{y},\theta)$ =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & cos(\theta) & 0 & -sin(\theta) \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & sin(\theta) & 0 & cos(\theta) 
 \end{pmatrix}

Differentiating with respect to $\theta$ we have

\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & -sin(\theta) & 0 & -cos(\theta) \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & cos(\theta) & 0 & -sin(\theta) 
 \end{pmatrix}

and then taking the limit as $\theta$ goes to zero, we get

$J_y$ =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}

To get $J_z$ we begin

$R(\hat{z},\theta)$ =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta) & 0 \\
  0 & sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)  & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
 \end{pmatrix}

Differentiating with respect to $\theta$ we have

\begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & -sin(\theta) & -cos(\theta) & 0 \\
  0 & cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)  & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}

and then taking the limit as $\theta$ goes to zero, we get

$J_z$ =
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
  0 & 1 & 0  & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 
 \end{pmatrix}

Now recalling the limits of hyperbolic trig functions,

\begin{eqnarray*}
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} [sinh(x)] &=&  cosh(x) \\
\frac{\partial}{\partial x} [cosh(x)] &=& sinh(x)
\end{eqnarray*}

as well as the value of the hyperbolic trig functions at 0,

\begin{eqnarray*}
cosh(0) &=& 1\\
sinh(0) &=& 1
\end{eqnarray*}

To get $K_x$ we begin

$\beta(\hat{x},\delta)$ =
 \begin{pmatrix}
 cosh(\delta) & -sinh(\delta) & 0 & 0 \\
 -sinh(\delta) & cosh(\delta)  & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
 \end{pmatrix}

Simultaneously differentiating with respect to $\delta$ and then taking the limit as $\delta$ goes to 0, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
K_x &=& -i
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -1 & 0 & 0 \\
  -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix} \\
 &=& i
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 \end{eqnarray*}

To get $K_y$ we begin

$\beta(\hat{y},\delta)$ =
 \begin{pmatrix}
 cosh(\delta) & 0 & -sinh(\delta) & 0 \\
 0 & 1  & 0 & 0 \\
  -sinh(\delta) & 0 & cosh(\delta) & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 
 \end{pmatrix}

Simultaneously differentiating with respect to $\delta$ and then taking the limit as $\delta$ goes to 0, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
K_y &=& -i
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & -1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  -1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix} \\
 &=& i
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 \end{eqnarray*}

To get $K_z$ we begin

$\beta(\hat{z},\delta)$ =
 \begin{pmatrix}
 cosh(\delta) & 0 & 0 & -sinh(\delta) \\
 0 & 1  & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
  -sinh(\delta) & 0 & 0 & cosh(\delta) 
 \end{pmatrix}

Simultaneously differentiating with respect to $\delta$ and then taking the limit as $\delta$ goes to 0, we have 
\begin{eqnarray*}
K_z &=& -i
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  -1 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix} 
 \\
 &=& i
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
  1 & 0 & 0 & 0
 \end{pmatrix}
 \end{eqnarray*}

Linked [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3204750/error-with-generators-of-lorentz-group-basis-of-lorentz-lie-algebra) from Math Stack

Comment: Well, your $R_y$ is off by a sign. If you want to see, just check what it does to a test vector like $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$. It rotates in the opposite sense to all the other ones.

Comment: Holy crap you're right, that $R_y$ rotates clockwise. Can you help explain why that is? I was under the impress that a counterclockwise rotation by an angle $\theta$ along the i-axis took precisely the form I listed. But you are absolutely correct, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix#Basic_rotations

Comment: It seems to have something to do with using a right-handed coordinate system but I can't place my finger on it

Comment: Note that $sin$ is interpreted as the product of the variables $s$, $i$ and $n$, rather than the operator $\sin$, which is obtained by writing `\sin`.